# Как отображать товары по категориям в React.js и при нажатии переходить на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

---

Добрый всем) получила все товары они вложены в категории и подкатегории как у поставщика апи, как мне реализовать чтобы при нажимании на категоию она открывалась на другой странице ? На данный момент при нажатии на категорию она разворачивается в низ с содержимым подкатегории в них товары, есть вложеность 3 уровня, есть 4 ! поскольку я прям новичек, то не могу понять как реализовать такой переход? Помогите плиз***

```
  `api.js 
`import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Search from "./SearchProducts/SearchProducts";
import AddProducts from "./AddProducts/AddProducts";
import CardBody from "./Card/CardBody";
import Button from "./Button/Button";
import CategoryButton from "./CategoryButton/CategoryButton";

import "./Api.css";

import axios from 'axios';

const CategoryTree = ({ section, toggleCategory, expandedCategories, categoryName, itemsByCategory, removeItem, addedItems, addItem, level }) => {
  //  рендеринг карточек товаров
  const sectionItems = itemsByCategory[section.id] || [];
  return (
    <div className="api-row">

      <CategoryButton
        level={level}
        onClick={() => toggleCategory(section.id)}
      >
        {categoryName(section.id)}
      </CategoryButton>
      {expandedCategories[section.id] && (
        <div className="api-col" >
          {sectionItems.length > 0 && (
            <CardBody
              category={section.name}
              products={sectionItems}

              addItem={addItem}
              removeItem={removeItem}
              addedItems={addedItems}

              onClick={() => toggleCategory(section.id)}

            />
          )}
          {section.children.map((childSection) => (
            <CategoryTree
              key={childSection.id}
              section={childSection}
              level={level + 1}
              toggleCategory={toggleCategory}
              expandedCategories={expandedCategories}
              categoryName={categoryName}
              itemsByCategory={itemsByCategory}
              addItem={addItem}
              removeItem={removeItem}
              addedItems={addedItems}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Api = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [addedItems, setAddedItems] = useState([]);
  const [showAddProducts, setShowAddProducts] = useState(false);
  const [expandedCategories, setExpandedCategories] = useState({});
  const [categoryTree, setCategoryTree] = useState([]);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState({});
  const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState(null);
  const url = 'http://localhost:8000/products/';

  useEffect(() => {
    // Загрузка товаров
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        const baseImageUrl = 'https://optfm.ru';
        const newItems = response.data.response.items.map(item => ({
          ...item,
          picture: baseImageUrl + item.picture
        }));
        setItems(newItems);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));

    // Загрузка категорий
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sections')
      .then(response => {
        const sections = response.data.response.items;
        const sectionsTree = buildCategoryTree(sections);
        const sectionsMap = {};
        sections.forEach(section => {
          sectionsMap[section.id] = section.name;
        });

        setCategoryTree(sectionsTree);
        setCategories(sectionsMap);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  function changingSearchData(e) {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  }

  const itemsFilter = items.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()));

  function addItem(item) {
    item.addNumber = 1;
    item.price = item.prices[1].price;
    const newItems = [...addedItems, item];
    setAddedItems(newItems);
  }

  function removeItem(item) {
    const newItems = addedItems.filter((addedItem) => addedItem.id !== item.id);
    setAddedItems(newItems);
  }

  // Функция для получения товаров по категориям
  const getCategoryItems = (items) => {
    const categoryItems = {};
    items.forEach(item => {
      if (!categoryItems[item.section_id]) {
        categoryItems[item.section_id] = [item];
      } else {
        categoryItems[item.section_id].push(item);
      }
    });
    return categoryItems;
  };

  // Получение товаров по категориям
  const itemsByCategory = getCategoryItems(items);

  const toggleCategory = (categoryId) => {
    setExpandedCategories(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [categoryId]: !prevState[categoryId],
    }));
  };

  const buildCategoryTree = (sections) => {
    const tree = {};
    sections.forEach((section) => {
      tree[section.id] = { ...section, children: [] };
    });

    Object.values(tree).forEach((section) => {
      if (section.parent_id) {
        tree[section.parent_id].children.push(section);
      }
    });

    return Object.values(tree).filter((section) => section.parent_id === null);
  };
  //

  // Функция обработки выбора категории
  const handleCategorySelect = (categoryId) => {
    setCurrentCategory(categoryId);
  };

  // Функция возврата к списку категорий
  const handleReturnToCategories = () => {
    setCurrentCategory(null);
  };
  // Получаем список товаров текущей категории
  const currentCategoryItems = items.filter((item) => item.section_id === currentCategory);

  // имя категории
  const categoryName = (categoryId) => {
    return categories[categoryId] || "Категория не найдена";
  };

  return (
    <div className="body__container">

      <div className="navigation__api">
        <div className="nav-right">
          <Search value={searchValue} onChangeData={changingSearchData} />
          <Button num={addedItems.length} click={() => setShowAddProducts(!showAddProducts)} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="add__products">
        {showAddProducts && (
          <div className="add__products">
            <AddProducts
              click={() => setShowAddProducts(!showAddProducts)}
              items={addedItems}
              removeItem={removeItem}
              setAddedItems={setAddedItems}
            />
          </div>

        )}
        {currentCategory === null ? (
          categoryTree.map((section) => (
            <CategoryTree
              key={section.id}
              section={section}
              level={0}
              toggleCategory={toggleCategory}
              expandedCategories={expandedCategories}
              categoryName={categoryName}
              itemsByCategory={itemsByCategory}
              addItem={addItem}
              removeItem={removeItem}
              addedItems={addedItems}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          categoryTree.filter(section => section.id === currentCategory).map((section) => (
            <CategoryTree
              key={section.id}
              section={section}
              toggleCategory={toggleCategory}
              expandedCategories={expandedCategories}
              categoryName={categoryName}
              itemsByCategory={itemsByCategory}
              addItem={addItem}
              removeItem={removeItem}
              addedItems={addedItems}
              currentCategory={currentCategory}
            />
          ))
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Api;  



 cardBody.js 
const CardBody = ({ category, products, addItem, removeItem, addedItems, subsectionName }) => {
    return (
        <div className="card__category">
            <h2 className="card-text">{category}</h2>
            <h3>{subsectionName}</h3>
            <div className="card__grid">
                {products.map((product) => (
                    <Card
                        key={product.id}
                        product={product}
                        addItem={addItem}
                        removeItem={removeItem}
                        addedItems={addedItems}
                        text={product.detail_text}
                        price={product.prices[1].price}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CardBody;`

`const CategoryButton = ({ children, onClick, category, level }) => {
  const levelClass = `category-card-level-${level}`;
  return (
    <div className={`category-card ${levelClass}`} onClick={onClick}>
      {children}
      <h2>{category && category.name}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategoryButton;`
`App.js  роут 

     <Route path="/api" element={<Api />} />`
плюс остальные роуты не относящиеся к товарам
```

Comment: Что значит "на другой странице"? А с этой как? Напомню что Реакт это таки про СПА. Т.е. приложение на одной странице.

Comment: Ну сейчас я в режиме теста и находясь на странице где я получаю товары http://localhost:3000/api , нажимаю на главную категорию и попадаю на http://localhost:3000/category/1234, и у меня не получается ни как настроить чтобы отображать содержимое этой категории . Не могу настроить роутинг